# Access a vector inside a struct that is inside a class

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm getting a runtime error when trying that scenario, and I get vector subscript out of range

```
struct Mesh
{
  std::vector<Vertex> mVertices;
}

class Grid
{

public:
Mesh mMesh;
}

Grid g_Grid;

g_Grid.mMesh.mVertices.reserve(40);
g_Grid.mMesh.mVertices[0] = 10; // allocation error
```

Comment: You didn't put anything in the vector, what do you expect?

Comment: `reserve()` is not `resize()`.

Comment: what do you mean I didn't put anything? I have reserves a 40 spaces and and I need to put element 0 to be 10

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant opps a stupid typo!

Comment: @andre let me reiterate, `reserve()` is not `resize()`. You need to **read the documentation** for those two methods before complaining.

Comment: No need to negate my question!. It was just a typo, I know the difference :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method reserve does not create elements of a vector. it only reserves memory for elements that can be added to the vector in future with for example method `push_back`

So write instead

```
g_Grid.mMesh.mVertices.reserve(40);
g_Grid.mMesh.mVertices.push_back( 10 );
```

Or if you want that the elements would  already exist then write

```
g_Grid.mMesh.mVertices.resize(40);
g_Grid.mMesh.mVertices[0] = 10;
```

If you want to add at once several elements to the vector that does not yet contain any elements then you can write

```
g_Grid.mMesh.mVertices.reserve(40);
g_Grid.mMesh.mVertices = { 10, 20, 30 };
```